# time-domain channel estimation based on two vectors optimization

Tags: estimation, optimization, convex-optimization, channel-estimation

Let's the input data vector $X = [X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5,X_6,X_7,X_8];$ where $[X_7,X_8]$ are well known, and the vector $y = h*X$ where $*$ is the convolution operation and $h = [h_1,h_2]$ is the channel vector.
I have a priory information that  $[X_7,X_8]$ = $T[X_1,X_2]$ where $T$ is a $2$x$2$ square matrix.

The issue I am trying to solve is can we get the channel vector $h$ based on optimizing $([y_7,y_8]$ - $T[y_1,y_2])$ ?  Is there any optimization algorithm we can use to estimate the vector $h$?

Comment: Do you know $T$? in that case, no need for optimization. It's straight forward writing down the linear system of equations giving $y[3]$ and $y[9]$ and solving that.

Comment: Also, if $T$ is invertible, then you know $X_1, X_2$, and then it's really trivial: $y[3]=[X_1,X_2]*[h_1, h_2]$, and $y[9]=[X_7, X_8] *[h_1,h2]$; write that down as matrix system $$\begin{pmatrix}y[3]\\y[9]\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}X_1&X_2\\X_7&X_8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_2\\h_1\end{pmatrix}$$ and solve it.

Comment: If you *don't* know $T$, well, your prior information is worth nothing (you can *always* find a $T$ that fulfills that condition) and your problem can't be optimized at all.

Comment: Yes, $T$ is well-known and invertible,  do you mean by $*$ the convolution operation  as in my question? or it's multiplication ?

Comment: and please write down the details as an answer in order to accept it and close the question.

Comment: yes, taht $*$ is convolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify that $T$ is known and invertible, so you know $X_1, X_2$, and then it's really trivial: $y[3]=[X_1,X_2]*[h_1, h_2]$, and $y[9]=[X_7, X_8] *[h_1,h_2]$; write that down as matrix system

$$\begin{pmatrix}y[3]\\y[9]\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}X_1&X_2\\X_7&X_8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_2\\h_1\end{pmatrix}$$

and solve it.